# How to add one more column for each sample?

Tags: tables

I want to add another column called "N" right before "Range" column for each sample. How to revise my code?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l ccc ccc @{}}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dyads Sample} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Committed Sample} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
  & Range & Mean & Sd & Range & Mean & Sd \\ 
  \midrule
  BAA & \{0,1\}\ & 0.362 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.306 &  \\ 
  BAF & \{0,1\}\ & 0.449 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.388 &  \\ 
  Data Science & \{0,1\}\ & 0.550 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.406 &  \\ 
  Life Science & \{0,1\}\ & 0.597 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.509 &  \\ 
  Engineer & \{0,1\}\ & 0.796 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.864 &  \\ 
  Previous Raised & (0,40.0] & 1.096 & 3.030 & (0,10.0] & 1.101 & 1.754 \\ 
  Max Raise & [0.2,27.7] & 2.026 & 2.658 & [0.2,20.0] & 2.947 & 2.947 \\ 
  Age & [0,18] & 3.157 & 2.738 & [0,11] & 3.188 & 2.307 \\ 
  Patent & \{0,1\}\ & 0.171 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.161 &  \\ 
  Committed & \{0,1\}\ & 0.0188 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 1 &  \\ 
  Amount (\$K) & [0,350] & 0.273 & 5.154 & [3,350] & 15.408 & 35.627 \\ 
  \midrule
  \#Obs & 18,618 & 18,618 & 18,618 & 330 & 330 & 330 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is my output:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

If I got properly what you're asking for, this should be what you need.
Otherwise tell me that I make some changes:
[image]

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l ccc ccc ccc@{}}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Dyads Sample} & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Committed Sample} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
  & N & Range & Mean & Sd & N &Range & Mean & Sd \\ 
  \midrule
  BAA && \{0,1\}\ & 0.362 &  && \{0,1\}\ & 0.306 &  \\ 
  BAF && \{0,1\}\ & 0.449 &  && \{0,1\}\ & 0.388 &  \\ 
  Data Science && \{0,1\}\ & 0.550 &  && \{0,1\}\ & 0.406 &  \\ 
  Life Science && \{0,1\}\ & 0.597 &  && \{0,1\}\ & 0.509 &  \\ 
  Engineer && \{0,1\}\ & 0.796 &  && \{0,1\}\ & 0.864 &  \\ 
  Previous Raised && (0,40.0] & 1.096 & 3.030 && (0,10.0] & 1.101 & 1.754 \\ 
  Max Raise && [0.2,27.7] & 2.026 & 2.658 && [0.2,20.0] & 2.947 & 2.947 \\ 
  Age && [0,18] & 3.157 & 2.738 && [0,11] & 3.188 & 2.307 \\ 
  Patent && \{0,1\}\ & 0.171 &  && \{0,1\}\ & 0.161 &  \\ 
  Committed && \{0,1\}\ & 0.0188 &  && \{0,1\}\ & 1 &  \\ 
  Amount (\$K) && [0,350] & 0.273 & 5.154 && [3,350] & 15.408 & 35.627 \\ 
  \midrule
  \#Obs && 18,618 & 18,618 & 18,618 && 330 & 330 & 330 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. One minor remark: neither `array` nor `multirow` are required for this particular tabular.

Comment: Oops. My fault! I had to do my own MWE using ad older example. I edit it immediately! Thanks a lot. Wooof

Comment: thank you so much!!

Comment: @user235424 you're welcome! If this solved your problem, don't forget to accept my solution ;D